# Variable stays undefined after assigning within Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to assign the variable "dish_data" to data that is returned from "dish_ref.get()," which returns a promise.

```
let dish_data;
var get_dish_data = dish_ref.get()
        .then(doc => {
            console.log('doc: ', doc);
            console.log('doc: ', doc.data());
            dish_data = doc.data();
            console.log('dish_data in promise: ', dish_data);
        });

 console.log('dish_data after promise: ', dish_data);
 const num_ratings = dish_data['num_ratings'];
```

"dish_ref" is a Google Firestore document. The console log for "doc" and "doc.data()" shows a firestore document and the dictionary data respectively. The console log also shows "dish_data" containing the information from "doc.data()" when within the promise but after the promise, "dish_data" is undefined.

I've tried creating an async function as follows...

```
async function myFunc() {

    var get_dish_data = await dish_ref.get();

  }

dish_ref.get().then(myFunc);

var dish_data = get_dish_data.data();
```

but I got a syntax error saying function was an unexpected token.

Comment: Just put all the code that uses the promise results inside the callback

Comment: I decided to go with this route but it did make my code more messy.  I would have preferred using async and await but like I wrote in my post, I keep getting that syntax error, and after some googling, it looked like an outdated Node version was the culprit but I'm using the latest version of Node so I have no idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` (as well as all functions that return a promise) are *asynchronous*, meaning they return immediately.  The callback provided to `then()` gets executed some time later when the async work is complete.

Your code looks like it's assuming that `get()` blocks execution of this code, which it does not.  The subsequent code that accesses `dish_data` is going to execute immediately after `get()` returns, which means it will be undefined.  It won't get defined until your callback is finally executed.

If you want to use the results of the `get()`, you should only do that in the callback, or pass it along to some other function from there.

If you want to use `async`, then you will have to also use `await` to effectively pause the execution of the function until `get()` yields its results.

You can watch my video series on using promises and async/await, which may help explain things.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCYhr_UMZkI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg

Comment: These videos were very helpful. Thank you!